# How to count the number of a char* in a char** variable?

Tags: c++

How can you determine the number of elements in a dynamically allocated `char**`?

For instance:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "cstring"

using namespace std;

// here we create a 6 element char**
char **func() {
    std::vector<std::string> vec = {"A", "Dynamically", "Allocated", "List", "of", "Strings"};
    char **arr = (char **) malloc((vec.size() + 1) * sizeof(char *));

    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        arr[i] = (char *) malloc(strlen(vec[i].c_str()) + sizeof(char));
        strcpy(arr[i], vec[i].c_str());
    }
}

// here is a failed attempt at writing a functions for counting elements in char** 
int get_num_elements_in_char_star_star(char **c) {

    // infinite while loop!
    while(c){
        // ?? 
        cout << c << endl;
        c++;
    }
}

int main() {
    char **c = func();

    int x = get_num_elements_in_char_star_star(c);
    cout << x << endl;


    return 0;
};
```

The output should (obviously) be 6. Is this at all possible? I found a related post about counting arrays which uses `sizeof(array)/sizeof(char*)` for counting number of elements in an array, but this doesn't work in this instance.

## Edit

This sounds like an `XY` problem (see comments) so let me explain `X`. I have a function like `func` which is exported via `extern "C"` to a shared library. Since I have allocated a `char**` I also need to free it. Currently this is my function:

```
    void free_c_char_star_star(char **c, int size) {
        if (!c)
            return;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if(c[i]){
                free(c[i]);
            }
        }
        free(c);
    }
```

But I would like to avoid having to use the `size` parameter by automatically determining the size of `c`

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  What is the high-level problem that you're attempting to solve?

Comment: Possibly - I have a `char**` that needs `free`ing, so I need to know how many elements there are to iterate over the `char**` and free each `char*` . My fall back if this isn't possible is to manually pass in a `int size`, but I'd rather have the function automatically determine the number of elements in the `char**`.

Comment: You're explaining your attempted solution -- what problem are you trying to solve?  That's what the XY link is alluding to.  Is it that you need to pass that `char **` to a function that takes `char **`, like maybe one of the `exec` family of functions?  Maybe `char **` is the wrong tool for the job (which is still unknown at this point).  Why not a `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: Okay, I've edited the question to try and explain `X`.

Comment: When you populate the `**arr` add a final element that is null, this will indicate the end of the array in the same waht that the char* strings are null terminated. From the quick look at your code you are already allocating the extra slot `(vec.size() + 1)` but you are leaving it uninitialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can you determine the number of elements in a dynamically allocated char**?

There are no `char*` objects "in" a `char**` variable. `char**` points to one `char*` object (or none if null or dangling). Whether that `char*` is within an array, and how big that array is, is something that cannot be determined from the `char**` variable alone.

There are two typical ways to determine the size of an array: Store the size separately (or store a pointer to end) or choose particular value to represent the end of the array. The latter approach is conventionally used with null terminated strings.

---

More about your use case: Since you appear to create the structure once, and destroy it in one go, there is a more optimal way to do the allocation: Allocate all of the rows once in a big block; Then allocate array for pointers into beginning of each line. This needs constant number of allocations rather than linear number of allocations in relation to number of rows.

This has the added benefit that the destruction function doesn't need to know the sizes of the arrays. The need for that information is not obviated entirely though, since you presumably will want to also access the elements at some point.

---

P.S. `func` is declared to return `char**` but it fails to return anything. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

P.P.S. Don't use `malloc` in C++.

Comment: The most common method to indicate the end of an array of char pointers pointed to by a `char **` is to use a null pointer. This method is used in every invocation of  `main`.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Interestingly, `main` uses both approaches. The length is also stored separately in the first argument of `main` (conventionally named `argc`).

Comment: Yes, but I thought that was obvious ;-).